# How to write custom test client of django?

Tags: django, testing

I read the documents about objects but cannot really figure out how to make custom class of test client. There is a document that describes [how to make custom test client.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#customizing-the-test-client) but cannot make it. I want to make the client to enforce csrf check. How can I make it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django comes with [csrf protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/), which will be tested as part of their test suite so you shouldn't have to duplicate this.

Comment: Finally, I take off csrf checking. Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your site :-)